# Get value of a specific param - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

In a specific controller I have the below list of params:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>"{\"id\":32,\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"created_at\":\"2014-04-10T13:13:40.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-04-11T18:10:15.000Z\"}"}
```

How I can get the value of email for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You value looks like json.

So try this

```
user_params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:user])
user_params[:email]
```

or

```
require 'json'
user_params = JSON.parse(params[:user])
user_params[:email]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
params[:user][:email] #=> "test@test.com"
```

Which gives you the params of `email` attribute of `user`.

Comment: How would you do this on a session?

Comment: sessions are stored in cookies, which have their own methods. You can try `cookies{:your_attribute]` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html @SEJU