# Rails: dynamic select on multistep form not keeping selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I am working on a multistep form for an order placement process following Ryan Bates's [Multistep Tutorial #217](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?view=asciicast) which uses a session. On the first step I have two select fields: one for countries (land) and a dynamic one for shipping services. After a land has been selected the shipping services are loaded into the second select field through javascript/jQuery and the total price is calculated through JS.

app/views/orders/_shipping_step.html.erb

```
<%= f.collection_select(:land_id, Land.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "select a country"}, {:id => 'lands_select'}) %>
<%= f.select(:shippingservice_id, options_for_select(@shippingservices.collect { |s| [s.name.titleize, s.id, {'data-price' => s.price}] }, :selected => f.object.shippingservice_id), {:prompt => "select a carrier"}, {:id => "shippingservices_select"}) %>
```

ajax script

```
$(document).on("change", "#lands_select", function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/carts/update_shipping/" + event.target.value,
    type: "GET",
  })
});
```

On the shipping details step of the multistep form I can choose a land, the corresponding options for shipment are loaded and I can choose one. When progressing to the payment step, I can place the order and everything works, but in case I want to return from the payment step to the order step to change something, the shipping services selector displays options for land_id = 1, while the land select displays the choose country, for example id 85.

I added `:selected => session[:cart_params]` to the shipping service select, but it does not appear to be working. `:selected => f.object.shippingservice_id` keeps priority or standard shipping options, but for Land_id 1.

How can I get this working? Is it the select field or the JS? Why doesn't the second select keep the chosen land in memory?

Thank you in advance!

LOG:

```
Started GET "/orders/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 27 22:08:52 +0100 2018
Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Land Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  CartItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `cart_items`.* FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`length`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`width`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  Shippingservice Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` WHERE `lands`.`id` = 1 AND (weightmin <= 50 AND weightmax >= 50 AND heightmin <= 3 AND heightmax >= 3 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = ‘1’) AND (lengthmax >= 210 AND widthmax >= 149)
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Hero Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `heros`.* FROM `heros` WHERE `heros`.`id` = 18 LIMIT 1
  Rendered orders/_shipping_step.html.erb (13.7ms)
  Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 23.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

Selecting the shipping country:

```
Started GET "/carts/update_shipping/85" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 27 22:09:27 +0100 2018
Processing by CartsController#update_shipping as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"85"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Land Load (66.9ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  CartItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cart_items`.* FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`length`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`width`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
  Shippingservice Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` WHERE `lands`.`id` = 85 AND (weightmin <= 50 AND weightmax >= 50 AND heightmin <= 3 AND heightmax >= 3 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = ‘1’) AND (lengthmax >= 210 AND widthmax >= 149)
  Rendered carts/_shippingservice.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered carts/update_shipping.js.erb (2.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 7.8ms | ActiveRecord: 68.6ms)
```

Progressing to the next step:

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 27 22:09:33 +0100 2018
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"ship_to_last_name"=>”surname”, "ship_to_address"=>”street”, "ship_to_city"=>”city”, "ship_to_postal_code"=>”postcode”, "phone_number"=>”somenumber”, "shippingservice_id"=>"27", "email"=>”something@example.tld”, "land_id"=>"85", "ship_to_first_name"=>”firstname”}, "authenticity_token"=>”somestring”, "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Continue"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Land Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  CartItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cart_items`.* FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`length`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`width`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
  Land Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` WHERE `lands`.`id` = 85 LIMIT 1
  Shippingservice Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` WHERE `shippingservices`.`id` = 27 LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Hero Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `heros`.* FROM `heros` WHERE `heros`.`id` = 18 LIMIT 1
  Rendered orders/_payment_step.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 13.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
```

Returning to the shipping details step:

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 27 22:09:35 +0100 2018
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>”somestring”, "utf8"=>"✓", "back_button"=>"Back"}
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Land Load (2.4ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  CartItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `cart_items`.* FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`length`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT MAX(`cart_items`.`width`) AS max_id FROM `cart_items` WHERE `cart_items`.`cart_id` = 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `lands`.* FROM `lands` 
  Shippingservice Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` WHERE `lands`.`id` = 1 AND (weightmin <= 50 AND weightmax >= 50 AND heightmin <= 3 AND heightmax >= 3 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = ‘1’) AND (lengthmax >= 210 AND widthmax >= 149)
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Hero Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `heros`.* FROM `heros` WHERE `heros`.`id` = 18 LIMIT 1
  Rendered orders/_shipping_step.html.erb (16.5ms)
  Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 24.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

**UPDATE**

This is the part from my `orders_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :initialize_cart

def new
  session[:order_params] ||= {}
  @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
  @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  @shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(:lands => {:id => session[:cart_params]})
end

def create
  session[:order_params].deep_merge!(params[:order]) if params[:order]
  @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
  @shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(:lands => {:id => session[:cart_params]})
  @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  if @order.valid?
    if params[:back_button]
      @order.previous_step
    elsif @order.last_step? && params[:commit] == 'Option A'
      …
    elsif @order.last_step? && params[:commit] == 'Option B'
      …
    else
      @order.next_step
    end
    session[:order_step] = @order.current_step
  end
  if @order.new_record?
    render "new"
  else
    # Empty the cart
    @cart.cart_items.destroy_all
    # Reset session
    session[:order_step] = session[:order_params] = nil
  end
end
```

When I specify an id such as through Land.first.id or Land.last.id, the query works and the back step appears to be working.

When using `session[:order_params]` I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#create` but the correct land_id is present:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'id.ship_to_last_name' in 'where clause': SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` 
INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` 
INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` 
WHERE `id`.`ship_to_last_name` = 'Smith' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_address` = 'Somewherestreet' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_city` = 'Nowheretown' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_postal_code` = '99999' 
AND `id`.`phone_number` = 'some number' 
AND `id`.`shippingservice_id` = '34' 
AND `id`.`email` = 'someone@example.tld' 
AND `id`.`land_id` = '85' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_first_name` = 'John' 
AND (weightmin <= 200 AND weightmax >= 200 AND heightmin <= 12 AND heightmax >= 12 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = '1') AND (lengthmax >= 210 AND widthmax >= 149)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `OrdersController`? On the back step the `Shippingservice Load` is running a query that has `WHERE lands.id = 1`.  Maybe this is a fall back for an undefined `@land` variable?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have been working on this since yesterday. `WHERE lands.id = 1` could be some sort of fallback. `params[:id]` should not be possible as far as I know, since I have not committed yet and nothing is written to the database. I would need to provide the id.land_id value from the orders_params somehow I guess.

Comment: Why are you calling `session[:cart_params]` for the land_id instead of grabbing it from the `session[:order_params]`? Sidenote: `‘Option A’` and B those quotes are weird and need to be changed into normal quotation marks.

Comment: I was wondering if I could add the land.id also to the `cart_session` from the `application controller`, but let go. I do not know how to grab it from the `session[:order_params]`. I was trying but could not figure out how to do it. If I put `session[:order_params]` he throws all parameters at the query.

Comment: `session[:order_params][:land_id]` perhaps? You should be able to view the structure of your session and grab the value from there

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020928/get-value-of-a-specific-param-rails, which is what you suggested for params. On first try `session[:order_params][:land_id]` does not appear to be working. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: How about `@order.land_id` or whatever relation it has? Then you are pulling it off the newly initialized `@order` and not relying on session.

Comment: YEAH! `@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(:lands => {:id => @order.land_id})` works! I always thought `@order.land_id` would work only with values which where already in the database! Please write your suggestion as a short answer, so that I can upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(:lands => {:id => session[:cart_params]})`

This was not correctly using the `session[:cart_params]` to get the `land_id` in order to set the orders land when moving back through the form.  We can instead use `@order = Order.new(session[:order_params])` defined one line above to grab `@order.land_id` and not have to rely on any of the sessions.

I would also add an existence check if there is a possibility of an Order being initialized without a corresponding Land.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful feedback!