# Rails: How to access session parameter / ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, activerecord, session-variables

I am working on a multistep form for an order placement section which uses a session `session[:order_params]` to store all form inputs before submit.

I need to be able to access a particular parameter (land) from the session in order to query for another resource (shippingservice) when navigating back in the form.

In my `orders_controller.rb` I have:

```
@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(:lands => {:id => params[:id]})
```

but would need to specify the land.id from the `session[:order_params]`.

When using `session[:order_params]` I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#create`:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'id.ship_to_last_name' in 'where clause': SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` 
INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` 
INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` 
WHERE `id`.`ship_to_last_name` = 'Smith' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_address` = 'Somewherestreet' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_city` = 'Nowheretown' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_postal_code` = '99999' 
AND `id`.`phone_number` = 'some number' 
AND `id`.`shippingservice_id` = '34' 
AND `id`.`email` = 'someone@example.tld' 
AND `id`.`land_id` = '85' 
AND `id`.`ship_to_first_name` = 'John' 
AND (weightmin <= 200 AND weightmax >= 200 AND heightmin <= 12 AND heightmax >= 12 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = '1') AND (lengthmax >= 210 AND widthmax >= 149)
```

Since the correct land_id is present I am wondering how to provide only that value to the query.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post, you want to access a particular key stored in session at a particular key.

Assuming order_params is a hash, you can get land_id using the below mentioned code:

```
session[:order_params][:land_id]
```

This will return the value of land_id and thus you can use it in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it does not work. I have more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953658/rails-dynamic-select-on-multistep-form-not-keeping-selected?noredirect=1#comment94754469_53953658

Answer (score 1):

To set session variable, you can set some data in a controller action
For eg:
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  # ...
  session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
  # ...
end
```

And read it in another: app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def index
  current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know, but in this case I need to access a value saved inside the order_params or do you mean I have to create another session or specify another session?